# Is my hardware conflicting, making AVD Extremely Slow?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Recently replaced motherboard and CPU along with fresh installed windows and Android Studio. However, the CPU does not have integrated graphics. I think that along with Android Studio settings is causing my problem but I'm not sure what else to try.

Currently Running
Win 10 1909
i3 9100F
Radeon HD 6670
4gb ddr4 2400

Android 10.0+ (R) (API level 30)
Nexus 4 API 27

I've installed the latest (revisions?) of all versions of SDK Build-Tools available.
I've specifically changed to a non-play store AVD.
I've disabled 'Multi-Core CPU'

I get a pop up warning an ADB binary is obsolete.

> "The ADB binary at
> C:\Users\ibeaw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe is
> obsolete and has serious performance problems with the Android
> Emulator. Please update to a newer version to get significantly faster
> app / file transfer".

*When running with graphics set to 'software - GLES 2.0':**
Gradle Build finishes quickly then the emulator takes forever to boot up while slowing the pc.

**When running with graphics set to 'Hardware - GLES 2.0' OR 'Automatic':**
PC freezes for a while and eventually logs the errors.

```
04:51   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 15001 ms

04:51   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU0 thread'. No response for 15051 ms

04:51   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU1 thread'. No response for 15051 ms

04:51   Emulator: Warning: restoring GLES1 context from snapshot. App may need reloading.

04:53   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44348 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:53   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44348 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:53   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

04:54   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44484 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:54   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44484 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:54   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

04:54   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44548 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:54   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44548 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:54   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

04:54   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 35988 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:54   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 35988 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:54   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

04:54   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44712 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:54   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44712 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

04:54   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
```

I need to be able to run the AVD with hardware-enabled, the software option is just unbearably slow.